# Silex login working one time after session deletion

Tags: silex

I implemented login on my silex project with SecurityServiceProvider and my own provider exactly as described in official documentation.

I can log in, then log out, but can not log in again until I manually remove the PHPSESSID.
Any idea ?

Here is the configuration :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());

$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'website' => array(
         'anonymous' => true,
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
        'users' => $app->share(
            function () use ($app) {
                return new \Project\Provider\UserProvider($app);
            }
        ),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout')
    )
);

$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
    array('^/private', 'ROLE_USER'),
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
);
```

Now my provider class :

```
namespace Project\Provider;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Project\Security\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Silex\Application;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $app,
            $conn;

    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app  = $app;
        $this->conn = $app['db'];
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?', array(strtolower($username)));

        if ( !$user = $stmt->fetch() ) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
        }

        if ( $user['enabled'] == 0 ) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('Account not validated.');
        }

        $userApp = new User($user['email'], $user['password'], $user['id'], array('ROLE_USER'));
        $userApp->setExtra($user);

        return $userApp;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === '\Project\Security\User';
    }
}
```

Now my user class :

```
namespace Project\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * User implementation used by the in-memory user provider.
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $id;
    private $enabled;
    private $accountNonExpired;
    private $credentialsNonExpired;
    private $accountNonLocked;
    private $roles;
    private $extra;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $id, array $roles = array(), $enabled = true, $userNonExpired = true, $credentialsNonExpired = true, $userNonLocked = true)
    {
        if (empty($username)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The username cannot be empty.');
        }

        if (empty($id)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The id cannot be empty.');
        }

        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
        $this->accountNonExpired = $userNonExpired;
        $this->credentialsNonExpired = $credentialsNonExpired;
        $this->accountNonLocked = $userNonLocked;
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @return int Current member id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return $this->accountNonExpired;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return $this->accountNonLocked;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return $this->credentialsNonExpired;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Stocks array containing pau_member fields
     * 
     * @param array $member
     */
    public function setExtra($member)
    {
        $this->extra = $member;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a given field value of current member
     * 
     * @param string $field. May be null
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getExtra($field = null)
    {
        if ( !is_null($field) ) {
            return $this->extra[$field];
        }

        return $this->extra;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I redefined logout controller.